# if statement running on false?

Tags: javascript

using javascript

I have a function

```
function test(variable)
{
  if(variable != 'undefined')
  {
     console.log('variable is not set');
     console.log('variable', where); 
  }
}
```

i call it using `test();`

yet in the console I get
   'where is not set'
    'where is set as undefined'

why?

---

**Update**
This function is not what i am actually using.

The function should not do anything if the variable is undefined.

the example was to show the if statement not working.

But the issue was actually me using if `variable != 'undefined'` instead of `variable != undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are testing whether `variable` has the *string content* of `"undefined"`.

What you probably want is

```
if(typeof variable != 'undefined')
```

The rest of the function is not making sense to me yet, either. Where does `where` come from?

Answer (score 6):

You have both `console.log` calls in the same `if` branch. Do this instead:

```
function test(variable)
{
  if(variable != 'undefined')
  {
     console.log('where is not set');
  }
  else
  {
     console.log('where is set as ', where); 
  }
}
```

Besides that: If you want to test if a variable is undefined, use the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator) to test the type: `typeof variable != 'undefined'`. Currently you just test if `variable` is not equal to the string value `'undefined'`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand your question but try using different paramater name instead of "variable". See if the error still there.

Plus call the function like this: test(paramterValueHere);

Best